# another windows 8 install problem acer 21.10

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows, secure-boot

I have been trying for two days to get may acer predator series g to recognize my boot dist. I have one dvd from Ubuntu user which worked on my laptop and one i burned my self 12.10 64 bit which should work. Reading through documintation http://www.itwire.com/opinion-and-analysis/open-sauce/57822-ubuntu-1210-and-windows-8-an-uneasy-marriage/57822-ubuntu-1210-and-windows-8-an-uneasy-marriage?start=1 and other sources I determined I had to turn secure boot off and try restart (holding shift key)or pressing f12 and getting boot options. In both cases the boot up disks are not seen.

My bios setup is as follows. 
Boot Option
Boot priority Order
1st boot Device [CD&DVD]
2nd Boot Device[Removable Device]]
3rd boot Device [hard Disk:UEFI: ST20...]

Authentication
System Boot State User
Secure Boot Mode State Disabled
Secure Boot [Disabled]

No legacy option from what I can see. So I am at a loss. Could 13.04 work or am I missing something. I don't have the Windows disk.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm brand new to linux in fact I'm downloading it as we speak but I do have some experience of installing windows 7/vista onto a uefi (windows 8) machine. The presence of UEFI over bios isn't brilliant imo it's pretty fiddley. On Windows 7 for example if you want to replace windows 8 with windows 7 you need to disbale secure boot then you can only install 64 bit versions (UEFI doesn't support 32 bit os's) of windows vista sp3/Windows 7 (home, pro or ultimate). To do this you need to make a bootable usb stick copy the version of windows onto that stick and then move a couple of files and rename a file to get the right UEFI compatible bootloader in place. You then need to boot from a bootable cd (something like norton 360 will do it which has and advanced option that allows you to access a command prompt once there you need to load diskpart and clean the partition and set it as active assigning a disk letter before any other os will install). Once the partition has been cleaned and set to active you can reboot from your usb stick and load windows 7.

I would Imagine you will need to do something similar I don't know if Ubuntu is uefi enabled from the cd. If so this will allow you to skip the moving renaming bit.

The windows guide is here http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html

I don't know if this will help as I said I'm pretty new to linux so I can't offer any advice on ubuntu and uefi but as I said I'm downloading it now so that hopefully will change soon :)

I have done the windows downgrade a number of times and until everything is right the uefi either wont see the bootable media and/or the media won't see the hard disk.